# Excel Cell Text Seems to Change when Double Clicking Cell

Tags: excel, vba

The problem I am having here or hope to understand is that the characters in a cell seem to change from a programmatic perspective between macro produced values then double clicking the cell (probably explaining this horribly). To explain further, I have a macro that pulls variable paragraph sized strings and puts them in each cell within a given range. The next thing I try do is to use another macro on the newly produced range to remove extra newlines (2+ consecutive newlines). For whatever reason, the macro fails and seems to not be interpreting the newlines. Once I manually doubleclick inside a cell though to where the text cursor appears then leave that cell to run the newline macro, it is then able to detect the newlines.

What's going on here? Do the characters have different uni-code values or something prior to double-clicking the cell? I have similar problems when trying to analyze the characters of a cell for other words as well only when the cell text was generated from a macro.

Comment: Where are the paragraphs taken from? Also, it might help if you could edit your question to include a sample of code that reproduces the problem in order to get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect some of what you call newlines are carriage return characters ASCII 13. When you enter a carriage return character in a cell manually excel converts it into a new line character (ASCII 10). After reading your question, I verified this by entering the formula "=CHAR(13)" into cell A1 and then copied and pasted its value in place. I entered the formula "=CODE(A1)" in cell A2 to evaluate the ASCII code of the character in A1 (13 at this point). I then double clicked into A1 and pressed Enter and (guess what?) the character was changed into a new line character (ASCII 10). I suspected the same would happen with CHAR(11), but that was not the case.

To solve your problem I suggest you first convert all occurances of `Chr(13)` to `Chr(10)` using something like

```
MyString = Replace(MyString, Chr(13), Chr(10))
' and if it were me, I would also add (just in case)
MyString = Replace(MyString, Chr(11), Chr(10))
```

In my experience some programs (e.g. Access reports if I am not mistaken) need a sequence of `Chr(10) & Chr(13)` (or the other way around) to physically display a new line in reports and therefore, if you pull a paragraph that has what appears to be 2 new line characters, then the actual string to achieve this would be `Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13)` and in excel you end up with 4 new line characters. Hope this helps.

Edit:

In case this persists, a way I would use to debug the situation is by printing all chars with their values and read the character code at the place that's causing the issue with something like this (code not tested):

```
Dim s As String
Dim i as Integer
For i = 1 to Len(MyString)
  s = Mid$(MyString, i, 1)
  Debug.Print s & ", " & Asc(s) 'Or perhaps AscW(s) for unicode
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @DecimalTurn Many thanks for the link. As you can guess I am new to SO and I am learning new things every day.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry Thank you very much for information! Your solution has helped me with the problem. The other issue I was having (but your solution solved it as well) was bolding specific words in the cell. The words would be correctly bolded but then once I double clicked the cell the bolded text would be off by two characters. Thanks again!